# What is the correct way to use virtual Python environments with Homebrew?

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, homebrew

I love Homebrew and use it to install almost anything on my Mac. However, there are some issues I keep running into. One of them is the issue of an orphaned Python environment.

Whenever I use `brew cleanup`, all older versions of Python are purged, which makes all existing environments unusable and will give the following error when launching Python:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/user123/.virtualenvs/my_env/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I am not looking for a way to fix the environment, but rather trying to understand what would be best practice here. Never to run `brew cleanup`?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but maybe you can use `brew pin` to stop older versions being affected by upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

`brew cleanup` isn't the most sensitive command, and will occasionally cause some issues. However, as brew doesn't cleanup after itself, sometimes it's a necessary evil. Ideally, brew cleanup doesn't break existing versions, otherwise you can simply repair the existing versions with `brew reinstall ...`.